# Apple insisting my ID info is not correct, but it is, what to do?

Tags: email, security, password

My Apple ID is an old email. I have just tried to update some apps but it's telling me my password I entered is wrong (it isn't).

Then I tried to reset my password. As my Apple ID is a no longer a working email, I chose the option to answer a security question. I put the answer in and it tells me my information is incorrect.

I know my Apple ID is an old email, but I also know that my password is NOT incorrect although they say it is.

What should I do? I know the information I'm giving is correct but Apple isn't accepting anything except my Apple ID (now a disfunctional email address) and my birthdate?

Comment: I would recommend using AppleCare to sort this out.

Comment: If your Apple ID is no longer a valid email address, a message about resetting or changing your password could've been sent to that email address and you wouldn't know about it. How are you certain that you know the current password for the account?

Comment: Yesterday I was told my AppleID password was no good, I went there and re-did it, now all is working.  Indeed, it turns out that my old password does not meet the new(?) security requirements (you know digits, upper and lower case, etc. required)---so I thought maybe that was what went wrong.  I was offered two possibilities to reset the password: have an email sent, or answer security questions.  I chose the email route, but that won'd help the OP...

Comment: Also, see this about what to do when old email no longer available... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32993/

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I'm 100% sure I have the correct password because I've been using it for years, and because I also saved it in LastPass _(and I don't have any 'password changed' emails)_.  The email address is still functional, and they even acknowledge it's the correct email on [this page](https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid), yet I still haven't received a 'forgotten password' email, hours later.  wtf apple.

Comment: Another thing that may be going wrong with passwords that I just ran into toaday

Answer (score 1):

I second that you should contact Apple support about this. There could be a few reasons why this is happening, but it's likely because the actual account name has been changed since you set up the account.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HE34

If you follow the steps in the article above it will tell you if there still is an Apple ID named after your old email address.