# Computer access to music attached to a very old email address

Tags: itunes, apple-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I unlock my iTunes account when my old e-mail is unavailable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32993/how-do-i-unlock-my-itunes-account-when-my-old-e-mail-is-unavailable)

For some reason my iPod music located on my computer has re-attached itself to a very old email address and I get an error that states my computer isn't authorized. I'm then asked to provide a password, of course no success there. They can't reset the password because I don't have access to the old email. I tried to add the old email to my current account, with no success. Suggestions?

Comment: I have linked to a question with many suggestions on how to reset the password. Does this cover your question? If not, please edit your question to include what steps you may have tried and where you are stuck.